# Use Excel SUMIF to add cells with custom number formatted dollar value

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a range of cells that contain dates and dollar amounts.  I'd like to total the cells with dollars.

The worksheet is formatted in columns like this:

```
Date    | Amount |Date    | Amount | ... for about 20 col.
        |        |        |        |
        |        |        |        |
        |        |        |        |
```

I've tried various versions of SUMIF but I can't get a formula that will ignore the dates and include the dollar values.  The dollar value cells have a custom number format that includes a $ sign.  But I haven't been able to get anything that can use the $ to distinguish the 2 types of cells.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your data stacked side by side like that? It makes working with it inherently difficult.  Date should be a single column and Amount should be a single column, then you can much more easily do sums or other data analysis.

Comment: I inherited this from somone else.  I'm trying to make an update without changing too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual numerical value may be useful but it will depend upon the nature of your data (which is conspicuous by its absence).

A day is **1**. A Date is 1 for every day past 31-Dec-1899. Today happens to be 42,537 and one year ago was 42,171. If no valid *amount* was larger than $40,000 then you can reliably use the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) or [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) function by discarding numerical amounts greater than [EDATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8)([TODAY()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), -12).

```
=sumif(a:z, "<"&edate(today(), -12), a:z)
=sumifs(a:z, a:z, "<"&edate(today(), -12))
```

Note the syntax differences between [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) and [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B).

Another approach would be comparing the column header labels in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616).

```
=sumproduct((a1:z1="amount")*a2:z999)
```

Do not use full column references with [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616). Always restrict your data ranges to the extents of your actual data.